# Optional thread safety (thread safe section only under condition)

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

As stated in the title i have this situation

```
lock ( _myLockObj )
{
    // protected section here ( select + update over SQL Tables)
}
```

That works great , but sometimes i do not need thread safety , because is guaranteed by datas that nothing wrong could happen (even if two thread run in parralel) but i need speed .
At the moment program can understand when threads could have threads safety problem and when not ( and when not i need to be fast as possible ) .

What i would achieve make is optionallity on that lock instruction , so that it become effective only if in proper condition is true .

eg :

```
lock ( _myLockObj ) && flag
```

I am pretty sure that lock keyword does not provide that semantics, what i would understand is what is the proper way to achieve that behavior.

Comment: When you say you do not need thread safety, do you mean that you know that the lock object could not possibly be locked? Or do you mean that it could be locked but nevertheless you still do not need to acquire it? (And if the latter, why not solve it by making the lock finer grained?)

Comment: My method is completly thread safe, so generally i do not need lock.
What is not thread safe is the table manipulation made using linq, because database is the shared resource accross each thread.
May occur that two thread try to commit two distinct manipulation over the same data and that is a problem.
That case is rare and i can understand when it may happen and when certainly can not (most data need only to be inserted and is guaranteed to be one time insertion).
When i am sure it can not be happen i wuold avoid the lock isntruction (to get speed)

Comment: @Skary It would probably be better to deal with it using a database transaction, not thread synchronization.

Comment: @Jakub I am scared about distributed transaction (that i need to enable in order to proceed in that way).
Not onyl, in past i had strange behavour using transaction as solution (expecially with linq Select + Update).
I have not a good view on which are the causes of my past probelms but finally i decided to avoid transaction, and i use that approach as much as i can.

Comment: The problem with `select` + `insert` is that it will try to get an exclusive lock after it gets a shared lock. Depending on transaction isolation level, it will result in releasing the shared lock right after `select` (and allowing a T1:Select - T2:Select - T2:Update - T1:Update sequence), or deadlocks if the lock is kept. You would need to get an exclusive lock first to make it work correctly (you should be able to fins some ways to do it on SO). A problem with thread synchronization is that it only works within a process (or machine if you use sth like named mutex)

Comment: @Jakub locking one process is acceptable, because i have only one process that handle my post request.
The problem is that process need to run on a machine that has not SQL Server DB installed on (so it must connect to a remote machine using distributed transaction).
About select + insert or select + update, my problem is that it not only deadlock (temporary) a request (that should be acceptable).
The problem is that if i use that approach, randomly (about once a day) my clustered index associated with table freeze (permanently deadlock) and i need to restart SQL Server..really strange issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lock` statement is a syntactic sugar for [`Monitor.Enter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498(v=vs.110).aspx) + [`Monitor.Exit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) in a `try/finally` block.

You can use these methods directly:

```
bool flag = false;
bool acquiredLock = false;
try
{
    if (flag)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_myLockObj, ref acquiredLock);
    }


}
finally
{
    if (flag & acquiredLock)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_myLockObj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the following is nicer:

```cs
private bool flag;

public T DoStuff() {
  T DoStuffUnsafe() {
    // ...
  }
  if (flag) {
    lock (_myLockObj) {
      return DoStuffUnsafe();
    }
  }
  else {
    return DoStuffUnsafe();
  }
}
```